# Rectified Gaussian distribution with cut-off point other than zero

Tags: normal-distribution

I am trying to figure out the pdf of Rectified Gaussian distribution with cut-off point other than zero, or actually, a shifted Rectified Gaussian distribution with cut-off point at zero.

Here is what I have got so far, let $X$ denote rectified Gaussian distribution with $\mu,\sigma^2$

$$f(x) = \Phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})\delta(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}U(x)$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function and $U(x)$ is the unit step function.

$\delta(x)=\begin{cases}
      +\infty, & \text{if}\ x=0 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$
and 
$U(x)=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x\leq0 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$

I am trying to get it to have a cut of point at $k$ instead of 0, what I am thinking is that in order to have a cut of point at $k$, should I just change $\delta(x)$ and $U(x)$ to $$\delta(x)=\begin{cases}
      +\infty, & \text{if}\ x=k \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases},\text{and}$$

$$U(x)=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x\leq k \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}.$$

But I am unsure if they are the correct way to do it.

Comment: And? What’s the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Oh I have forgotten to include what I have got, I have edited the original question

Comment: For any function, or distribution for that matter, shifting with k is just: $f(x) \to f(x-k)$.

Comment: But only by doing this, I would also get the cut-off point shifted, i.e. the cut-off point would now become $k$ instead of 0

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about what you want. But I think it's actually this: the rectified gaussian is what you obtain when you take an arbitrary gaussian, take all the mass left of a point k and concentrate it at the point k. Keep the rest of the mass on the right like it was.

Comment: Sorry that my question was a bit unclear, I think I am looking for what you are saying, take everything at the left of $k$ and keep everything at the right as usual. But I wonder if my representation in the main question is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the density of a standard normal as $\phi(x)$ and the cumulative distribution as $\Phi(x)$, then the rectified Gaussian as above can be written as

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma) = \Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\delta(x)+\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)U(x)$$

and the generalization you're looking for as

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma,k) = \Phi\left(\frac{k-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\delta(x-k)+\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)U(x-k) \; .$$

It should be clear from the description I gave in my comment: "*the rectified gaussian is what you obtain when you take an arbitrary gaussian, take all the mass left of a point k and concentrate it at the point k. Keep the rest of the mass on the right like it was.* "

Comment: Thanks for your help!